# How to add a color from android resource file to Paint object?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, canvas

I want to know how to add a color from andoid resource file colors.xml to Paint object? 
The way I do it so far is

```
Paint orange = new Paint();
orange.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
```

But my problem is that getColor() is deprecated and I do not know which method should be used instead. Did anyone have the same problem and found a solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code;

```
     Paint orange = new Paint();
     orange.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.your_color));
```

Answer (score 0):

**if you use in Activity at that time use below code:-**

```
 Paint orange = new Paint();     
 orange.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.yourcolor));
```

**if you use in Fragment at that time use below code:-**

```
 Paint orange = new Paint();     
 orange.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.yourcolor));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.orange)` instead of `(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange)`